# Beautifying the Url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this link 
`http://xxxx.com/yyyy/index.php?class=Applications&function=create`

and I want to make it look like this

`http://xxxx.com/yyyy/create`

I know that I have to use the

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ..................

But Since I'm new at it, I don't know how to format it..

```
DirectoryIndex index.php order deny,allow Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

 RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^(XXXXXXXX)/(aaaa)/?$ $1/index.php?class=Applications&function=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(XXXXXXXX)/(bbbb)/?$ $1/index.php?class=Applications&function=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(XXXXXXXX)/(cccc)/?$ $1/index.php?class=Applications&function=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(XXXXXXXX)/(dddd)/?$ $1/index.php?class= test&function=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(yyyy)/index\.php$ $1 [L,NC]  #this one is not working...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(yyyy)/(create)/?$ $1/index.php?class=Applications&function=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you! It works just fine now.I was wondering if you could help me out, with this...now I get xxxx.com/yyyy/index.php. How do I get rid of the index.php? what rewrite rule is used for that.

Comment: You can use an additional rule for that: `RewriteRule ^(yyyy)/index\.php$ $1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Hm...this now works... http://xxxxx/index/Applications but this doesn't  - http://xxxxx/Applications/create

Comment: Please post your full .htaccess in your question (not in comments) and tell me which URI isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yyyy/
    RewriteRule create index.php?class=Applications&function=create
</IfModule>
```